# Array not getting spliced in DOM but in console it is - Ionic 2+/Angular2+

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

I have a dynamic `array` full of items and values. When the user clicks a button on the item, it should remove the item from the view list. I'm all out of guesses as to why this is. Would it be how the data is structured? I wouldn't think so because it shows that it's being removed in the console. Anyways Thanks!

**TS:**

```
export class Page{
    items: Item[];

    constructor(public alertCtrl: AlertController){}

    removeitem(i) {
        let confirm = this.alertCtrl.create({
            title: 'Confirm',
            message: "text.",
            buttons: [
                {
                    text: 'Cancel',
                    handler: () => {
                        console.log('Disagree clicked');
                    }
                },
                {
                    text: 'Save',
                    handler: () => { 
                        this.presentToast() 
                        this.items.splice(i, 1);

                    }
                }
            ]
        });
        confirm.present();
    }

getItems(){
   this.stopService.getItems().subscribe(item => { 
     this.items = item 
  })

  }


}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items; index as i ">
    <h3>{{item.description}}</h3>
    <button item-end ion-button full (click)="removeitem(i)">remove item</button>
</div>
```

**EDIT**

adding service how I get the items --

```
getItems(): Observable<any> {
         return this.http.get(someEndpoint)
        .map(res => res.json());
    }
```

Comment: How do you get/set items?

Comment: Sounds like Angular doesn't detect the change.

Comment: The thing is I was able to get the splice working in the DOM with fake data, not dynamic data. Basically doing the same thing.

Comment: Also added the service

Comment: Unrelated:in  let items = this.http.get(someEndpoint).map(res => res.json());
return items; map already return the value, so you can do return this.http.get(someEndpoint).map(res => res.json());

Comment: Try using observables with an async pipe in the *ngFor. You could use a behaviorSubject and use next to submit whole array on load/remove - then use it as an observable. I did something similar here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42020222/adding-session-timeout-for-angular-2-authentication-front-end/45805786#45805786

Comment: Also you know about page lifecyle in ionic too - be sure to check out this article. https://saniyusuf.com/ionic-by-component-page-lifecycle/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try to do the following:

```
removeitem(i) {
        let confirm = this.alertCtrl.create({
            title: 'Confirm',
            message: "text.",
            buttons: [
                {
                    text: 'Cancel',
                    handler: () => {
                        console.log('Disagree clicked');
                    }
                },
                {
                    text: 'Save',
                    handler: () => { 
                        this.presentToast() 
                        this.items = [...this.items.filter((item, index) => index !== i];
                    }
                }
            ]
        });
        confirm.present();
    }
```

This completely changes the object reference and should trigger a DOM update.

If this does not work, try to wrap your splice in a setTimeout:

```
setTimeout(() => { this.items.splice(i, 1); }, 0);
```

You can also try to inject `public zone: NgZone` in the constructor and run
splice in `this.zone.run(() => { this.items.splice(i, 1); });`. This is another way of forcing change detection.

**EDIT:**

In your `getItems()` method, try to do this:

```
    getItems() {
       this.stopService.getItems().subscribe(item => { 
         this.items = [...item];
      });
   }
```

Plunker reference:

[Plunker demonstration](https://plnkr.co/edit/1QqY0EUuP236Agqh2Li4?p=info)

Comment: Getting the same result for both options :(

Comment: Still not working..this is what I'm seeing in the console as well -- so the array is still being spliced..just not being shown in the DOM --              
     (22) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}] .                     (21) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]

Answer (score 4):

Seem like Angular change detector did not trigger. You can manually call it:

```
import {  ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';
constructor(private changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef  ){

}
removeitem(i) {
        let confirm = this.alertCtrl.create({
            title: 'Confirm',
            message: "text.",
            buttons: [
                {
                    text: 'Cancel',
                    handler: () => {
                        console.log('Disagree clicked');
                    }
                },
                {
                    text: 'Save',
                    handler: () => { 
                        this.presentToast() 
                        this.items.splice(i, 1);
                        this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();//call ng2 change detector here
                    }
                }
            ]
        });
        confirm.present();
    }
```

Comment: This solution does not work. I am getting undefined for the changes detected

Comment: Where did you get undefinded? Did you declare `changeDetectorRef` in constructor?

Comment: yes and I just console logged the this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges()

Comment: Hmm... It is a function. If it does not return a value, the default value is undefinded

Answer (score 4):

Remove `let items =` and put below code

```
getItems(): Observable<any> {
         return this.http.get(someEndpoint)
        .map(res => res.json());
    }
```

see this link for more [Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39819392/cannot-find-a-differ-supporting-object-object-object-of-type-object-ngfor)

Answer (score 3):

As @robbannn said, angular doesn't detect the change, so change

`this.items.splice(i, 1);`

To

`this.item = this.items.splice(i, 1).slice()`

Comment: It's still not removing the object from the DOM unfortunately with slice included.