# session timeout issue in angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

i implemented this code for session timeout like if system is idle system should redirect to login page 
but when system becomes idle it does not redirect to login page instead it stuck the system and cannot click on anything and when i refresh the page then it goes to login page.

here is my related **piece of service** -

```
private interval: any;
private TIMEOUT_IN: number = 1000 * 60 * 1.5; // 1.5 minutes
private redirectUrl: string;

constructor(public router: Router) {}

refreshTimer() {
    if (this.interval) {
        clearInterval(this.interval);
    }

    let lastTimeoutRefreshTimestamp = Number(
        sessionStorage.getItem("lastTimeoutRefreshTimestamp")
    );

    this._validateLastRefreshTimestamp(lastTimeoutRefreshTimestamp);
    this._updateLastRefreshTimestamp(lastTimeoutRefreshTimestamp);

    this.interval = setInterval(() => {
        sessionStorage.clear();
        clearInterval(this.interval);
        this._toTimeoutRoute();
    }, this.TIMEOUT_IN);
}

setRedirectUrl(url: string) {
    this.redirectUrl = url;
}

/**
 * Validates the last saved session refresh timestamp
 */
private _validateLastRefreshTimestamp(lastTimeoutRefreshTimestamp) {
    let currentTimestamp = Date.now();
    if (
        lastTimeoutRefreshTimestamp !== 0 &&
        lastTimeoutRefreshTimestamp < currentTimestamp
    ) {
        sessionStorage.clear();
        this._toTimeoutRoute();
    }
}

/**
 * Updates the timeout refresh timestamp stored in session storage
 */
private _updateLastRefreshTimestamp(lastTimeoutRefreshTimestamp) {
    lastTimeoutRefreshTimestamp = Date.now() + this.TIMEOUT_IN;
    sessionStorage.setItem(
        "lastTimeoutRefreshTimestamp",
        String(lastTimeoutRefreshTimestamp)
    );
}

/**
 * Correctly redirect to timeout modal depending the base bath in     redirectUrl
 */
private _toTimeoutRoute() {
    if (this.redirectUrl.indexOf("portal") > -1) {
        this.router.navigate(["/timeout"]);
    } else if (this.redirectUrl.indexOf("admin-portal") > -1) {
        this.router.navigate(["/admin-portal/timeout"]);
    } else {
        console.log("Redirect url was not set. Something went wrong.");
        throw new Error("redirectUrl not set in session-timeout service");
    }
}
```

And my **component part** -

```
this.sessionTimeoutService.setRedirectUrl("/admin-portal/login");

this.mousemoveRemoveListener = this.renderer.listen(
    "window",
    "mousemove",
    () => this.sessionTimeoutService.refreshTimer()
);

this.mousedownRemoveListener = this.renderer.listen(
    "window",
    "mousedown",
    () => this.sessionTimeoutService.refreshTimer()
);

this.keypressRemoveListener = this.renderer.listen(
    "window",
    "keypress",
    () => this.sessionTimeoutService.refreshTimer()
);

this.mousewheelRemoveListener = this.renderer.listen(
    "window",
    "mousewheel",
    () => this.sessionTimeoutService.refreshTimer()
);
```

when session is cleared page get stuck and when refresh it goes to the login 
and error is **redirect-Url is not set**
can someone help me? thanks

Comment: Make `_toTimeoutRoute` an arrow function or `bind` it to `this` in the constructor.

Comment: can you please eleborate? @MjZac

Comment: I already answered a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42020222/adding-session-timeout-for-angular-2-authentication-front-end/45805786#45805786

Comment: can you tell me whats wrong with this code? @JGFMK
redirectUrl is not set this is the error